# Mumble not installing on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: voip, mumble

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get install -f mumble`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mumble : Depends: libavahi-compat-libdnssd1 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt-get clean` reports no errors. Updates are set to Security, Updates, Backports.

Is there solution to the broken packages error that will allow install of mumble?

Comment: *you have held broken packages* is your problem. Have you added third-party repositories (PPA)?

Comment: I found a glitch in the package system whereas there were two entries for Canonical Partners in my sources lists. They appeared identical so I deleted the second entries (binary & source) I had not edited the sources by hand and only used PPAs added from the command line. After a refresh with 'update' and applied an 'upgrade' did the package blockage cleared itself. After that mumble did install properly.